# Total boundness of Lipschitz densities

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, statistics, probability-theory

In the article Almost Sure Testability of Classes of Densities by Devroye and Lugosi in 1999. They claim in Example 10 (page 9) that Lipschitz densities on [0,1] with Lipschitz constant bounded by some $C$ are a closed set and are as a class of densities totally bounded.

Why is this? I cannot find a proof of it.

Comment: Would you provide a fuller citation for the paper (I presume) you refer to by "Devroye and Lugosi 1990"?

Comment: Here is a link http://repositori.upf.edu/bitstream/handle/10230/1024/375.pdf?sequence=1 it is example 10 (page 9) where total boundedness is needed for apply the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some context: a *density* means a nonnegative integrable function on $[0,1]$ with integral equal to $1$. Total boundedness is understood in the $L^1$ norm.

Let $\mathcal F_C$ be the set of $C$-Lipschitz densities. I'll prove that it is totally bounded in the uniform norm $\sup|f|$, which will imply total boundedness in the $L^1$ norm (since the $L^1$ norm does not exceed the uniform norm.)

1. For every $f\in \mathcal F_C$ and every $x\in [0,1]$ we have $0\le f(x)\le C+1$. The lower bound is by definition of density. If the upper bound fails, that is $f(x)> C+1$ for some $x\in [0,1]$, then the Lipschitz condition implies $f(t)>1$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. But then $\int_0^1  f(t)\,dt>1$, a contradiction.
2. The family $\mathcal F_C$ is [equicontinuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity). Indeed, we can take $\delta=\epsilon/C$ in the definition of equicontinuity.

From 1 and 2, using the [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascoli%27s_theorem), we conclude that $\mathcal F_C$ is compact with respect to the uniform norm, and therefore is totally bounded.

Comment: Yes many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the class of Lipschitz densities with Lipschitz constant bounded by $C>0$. Topologically, we regard $\mathcal{F}$ as a subspace of $L^{1}[0,1]$.

We first show that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed in $L^{1}$. Suppose $(f_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset\mathcal{F}$ converges to $f\in L^{1}$. Passing to a subsequence if necessary, we may assume by Riesz-Fischer that $f_{n}(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ almost everywhere (a.e.). So for a.e. $x,y\in[0,1]$,
$$\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(y)\right|\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}C\left|x-y\right|=C\left|x-y\right|$$
Modifying $f$ on a set of measure zero if necessary, we may assume that $f$ is Lipschitz on $[0,1]$.

We now show that $\mathcal{F}$ is totally bounded in $L^{1}$. I claim that $\mathcal{F}$ is uniformly bounded by $1+C$. Indeed, by Weierstrass's Extreme Value Theorem, any $f\in\mathcal{F}$ attains its minimum and maximum at points $x_{\min},x_{\max}\in[0,1]$, respectively. Therefore
$$\sup_{0\leq x,y\leq 1}\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|\leq\left|f(x_{\max})-f(x_{\min})\right|\leq C$$
Since $\int_{0}^{1}f=1$, $0\leq f(x_{\min})\leq 1$, whence $f(x_{\max})\leq 1+C$. Define $M:=\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}f(x_{\max})$ (where $x_{\max}$ depends on $f$).

For integer $n\geq 1$, consider the step functions of the form
$$f_{i_{1}\cdots i_{n}}:=\dfrac{i_{1}M}{n}\chi_{[0,M/n]}+\dfrac{i_{2}M}{n}\chi_{[M/n,2M/n]}+\cdots+\dfrac{i_{n}M}{n}\chi_{[(n-1)M/n,M]}$$
where $i_{k}\in\left\{0,1,\ldots,n\right\}$ for $1\leq k\leq n$. Let $f\in\mathcal{F}$. On the interval $[jM/n,(j+1)M/n]$, let $i_{j}$ be such that $i_{j}M/n\leq f(jM/n)<(i_{j}+1)M/n$. Then

$\begin{align*}
\left|f(x)-\dfrac{i_{j}M}{n}\right|&\leq\left|f(x)-f\left(\dfrac{jM}{n}\right)\right|+\left|f\left(\dfrac{jM}{n}\right)-\dfrac{i_{j}M}{n}\right|\\
&\leq C\dfrac{M}{n}+\dfrac{M}{n}\\
&=(C+1)\dfrac{M}{n}
\end{align*}$
Hence,
$$\displaystyle\int_{[\frac{jM}{n},\frac{(j+1)M}{n}]}\left|f-\frac{i_{j}M}{n}\right|\leq(C+1)\dfrac{M^{2}}{n^{2}}$$
For $\varepsilon>0$ given, we can take $n$ sufficiently large so that the $(C+1)M^{2}/n<\varepsilon$, from which it follows that the open balls of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at the functions $f_{i_{1}\cdots i_{n}}$ totally bound $\mathcal{F}$.